# Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27

Tags: gradle

when i add new version of api 27 that error created i am beginner in android programming and online search for that error could not help

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
```

my windows is 10 32bit 
and android studio 2.3.3